# React: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created react gallery which allows user to upload an image into firebase storage, then firestore reads its urls and displays in my app.

I basicaly loop through an array of images (named docs) created and exported in other file. Now I want to add possibility to delete the file so before I remove it from firebase storage I want to remove the document from firestore database.

Now, I want function `deleteDocument` to remove document by method `deleteDoc` provided by firebase.

When I fire it I get an error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id').`

Seems like id is undefined but when I look into Dev Tools I clearly see there is id field (example: id: "REqWGEahJF2iqsdROM"). I have tried to get into component I want to delete by `ref.current` and `ref.doc.id`. I've been working on it for last few days and really I got no idea how to fix it :/

When I replace `compRef.doc.id` with `compRef.current` I got this error: `Uncaught TypeError: n.indexOf is not a function.`

```
import React from "react";
import { projectFirestore } from "../../firebase/config";
import { deleteDoc, doc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import useFirestore from "../../hooks/useFirestore";

const ImageGrid = ({ setSelectedImg }) => {
const compRef = React.useRef();
const { docs } = useFirestore('images');


const deleteDocument = () => {
  console.log(compRef);
  const docRef = doc(projectFirestore, 'images', compRef.current)

  deleteDoc(docRef).then(() => {
    console.log(`removed doc ${compRef.current}`)
    })
  }


  return (
    <div className="img-grid">
    { docs && docs.map(doc => (
    <div className="img-wrap" key={doc.id}
      ref={node => compRef.current = node}
      onClick={() => setSelectedImg(doc.url)}>
      <img src={doc.url} alt="uploaded img" />
      <button className="delete" 
        onClick={deleteDocument}
      >Delete</button>
    <div>
    ))}
    </div>)
  }
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

EDIT:
answer to console.log object compRef

```
current: div.img-wrap
__reactFiber$ars7zzthpl: FiberNode {tag: 5, key: null, elementType: 
'div', type: 'div', stateNode: div.img-wrap, …}
__reactProps$ars7zzthpl:
children: (2) [{…}, {…}]
className: "img-wrap"
onClick: () => setSelectedImg(doc.url)
...
id: ""
```

I think you dont need more properties of that object.
Now I see id field is empty, so is key. Still cannot solve this :(
When I console log docs array (compRef is reference to docs) then I see:

```
id: "REqWGEahJFQh2iqsdROM"
```

Comment: could you share what object you get when you `console.log(compRef)`?

Comment: Edited, hope this helps

Comment: try to console log docRef as well and see what comes out of it, it could be undefined.

Comment: When I try to console log docRef (no matter if the last argument is compRef, compRef.id or compRef.current) im getting this error:                         
    TypeError: n.indexOf is not a function
    at Function.fromString (index.esm2017.js:1081:1)
    at Dc (index.esm2017.js:15038:1)
    at deleteDocument (ImageGrid.js:16:1)